# Are lanternfish real?

Tags: zoology, marine-biology, ichthyology

Is there a real lantern fish existing in the world? If yes, kindly share a picture if one exists. I searched online for images, but most of them seem to be fake. The pictures I have seen on the internet were of a fish with a hanging lantern over its head. Are these possibly real pictures?

Comment: Do you have a picture? And yes, these fish are real.

Answer (score 4):

Fish you are referring to by description "fish with a hanging lantern over its head", are not lanternfish. Fish with "lantern" bait above head are members of group of fish named anglerfish (Lophiiformes).

You can find more information about them here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglerfish

Lanternfishes or **myctophids** are smaller fish that use bioluminecence for communication during mating season.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanternfish

Comment: Any added image would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

As Domagoj mentions in his [answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/58815/16866), it sounds like you are actually referring to an [anglerfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglerfish) (family *Lophiiformes*) and not a [lanternfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanternfish) (family *Myctophidae*).

Assuming this is the case, you can see video footage of the [Black Seadevil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_seadevil) (genus *Melanocetus*), a deep-sea anglerfish [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VqPMP9X-89o).

I've copied some footage from the video (from [MBARI](https://www.mbari.org/)*) below as gifs:

[image]

[image]

The Aquarium video provides the following description:

> Deep-sea anglerfish are strange and elusive creatures that are very rarely observed in their natural habitat. Fewer than half a dozen have ever been captured on film or video by deep diving research vehicles. This little angler, about 9 cm long, is named Melanocetus. It is also known as the Black Seadevil and it lives in the deep dark waters of the Monterey Canyon. MBARI's ROV Doc Ricketts observed this anglerfish for the first time at 600 meters on a midwater research expedition in November 2014. We believe that this is the first video footage ever made of this species alive and at depth.

You can see footage of another species of anglerfish [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cl_MbvSUvTk).

*MBARI = Monterey Bay Aquarium Research Institute.